# API Gateway: selecting backend using consistent hash on a request parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-api-gateway

Does API gateway support using consistent hash on a request parameter to select the upstream backend to route the request to?

Something like:
https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/consistent_hash/

I want all requests matching a certain criteria, identified through the hash of request,  to be sent to same backend server. For example,  if I have 5 different backend servers and have 1 million end users send requests wit 5 different IDs in the url, then I want each backend server to process requests with just 1 ID.

Comment: AFAIK there is no such an option. Could you describe in greater scope what your intention is? Maybe there is other way to achieve the same result.

Comment: Updated the original post with more details.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of this option on API Gateway directly.

However, quite in complicated way, you can integrate API Gateway with the ALB. Then, in ALB, you can configure multiple listeners with rules requiring the desired hashes in request query parameter. For each of those listeners you will assign a target group with the backend server instance.

See documentation for details

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-private-integration.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/create-listener.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/target-group-register-targets.html